# How to convert elastic query to NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am new to elastic search. I have this elastic query which I want to convert into NEST.

```
GET _search
{
 "from": 0,
 "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
   "stock": {
     "terms":{
       "order" : {
         "_term" : "asc" 
       },
       "script" : {
         "inline": "Math.sin(17*(double)doc['dealerId'].value) + '_' + doc['dealerId'].value",
         "lang": "painless"
       },
       "size":5
     },
     "aggs": {
       "sample":{
         "top_hits": {
             "sort": [
             {
               "_script": {
                  "type": "number",
                  "script": {
                     "lang": "painless",
                     "inline": "Math.sin(34*(double)doc['sortScore'].value)"
                  },
                  "order": "asc"
               }
             }
           ],
           "size" : 1
         }
         }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

So far, I have tried this.

```
client.Search<StockBaseEntity>(ss => ss
              .From(0)
              .Size(0)
              .Aggregations(agg => agg
                .Terms("stock", t => t
                    .Script(script => script
                                .Inline("Math.sin(5*(double)doc['dealerId'].value)+'_'+doc['dealerId'].value")
                                .Lang("painless"))
                    .OrderAscending("_term")
                    .Size(5)
                    .Aggregations(ag => ag
                                    .TopHits("sample", t11 => t11.Sort(st => st    --------->Now I don't know How can I achieve next part as ".Script" is not present  
                                        ))))));
```

`TopHitsAggregationDescriptor` does not contain `.Script` due to which I am not able sort document the way I want. Elastic query is working totally fine, so how can I convert it to nest? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: what version of NEST are you using and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: Nest version-5.0.0.0 same for elastic

Comment: looks like these are missing. I've added an issue to include them: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2913. In the meantime, you can use the low level client exposed through `.LowLevel` to send the request, and return a `SearchResponse<T>`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-getting-started.html#_searching_2 (see the note)